# htaccess url redirect with predefined strings(words)

Tags: url

Please help me to solve this problem. My project manager want that

In address bar if user type predefined strings, After http:// it should redirect
to given url

firstly user must type http://localhost/task/htaccess url & then

example  if  user types

http://one
it should redirect to google.com

or
http://two
redirect to google.com

Please help me to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Windows:

1) Open up the hosts file which can be found in the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc directory

2) Add the following line to the bottom of the file

```
google.com  one
```

3) Save the file

This needs to be done on every computer you want this to work for. So this means it will only be feasible internally (i.e. your company or internal network). You can't get computers outside your control to do this without having them knowingly install software that does it for them or providing them instructions. If you do this without their knowledge or permission you will be breaking laws.

Comment: "Internally", this can be done using DNS too.

Comment: Very good point. As a web developer this is as much as I know as I use this for internal testing. It allows me to set up domains for each site I am working on. Hopefully someone here can show them how to do this with internal DNS.